# How should I create a module in Phoenix/Elixir application I'm going to call regularly via cron?

Tags: cron, elixir, phoenix-framework

Say, I have a job I want to run on a regular basic, in background and I'll run it via cron.

How should I create it, should it be a module in "my_app/lib/my_module.ex" or what? If so, how would I call it via cron? Or should I create it in a separate project? And again -- what's would the command line for running it be?

If it was ruby, it'd be pretty straightforward -- I'd just call by its full path, but in Elixir/Phoenix it's not the case.

Comment: How are you deploying the application? Do you have `mix` and the complete source available on the server (if so, you can create a .exs file and do `mix run /path/to/that.exs`)?

Comment: @Dogbert, the source is only locally, I'm deploing via edeliver for now.

Comment: Why use cron? Elixir has enough ways to run scheduled tasks. Start a GenServer and have it send itself a delayed message that triggers the work and re-sends the delayed message. Simpler than having to fiddle around with cronjob maintenance. See for example https://github.com/c-rack/quantum-elixir

Comment: @Dogbert, so what you think?

Comment: By using an script as @Dogbert mentioned, you can just schedule it with cron easily. But I agree with cdegroot. If you can manage it inside your application, you also get benefits of the runtime system, your supervision tree, failure handling, release management and everything. It would be just another process in your application. Also, it can communicate with the rest of your application more easily.

Comment: @vfsoraki, I am able to, what's next? The question isn't about that.

Comment: @Daamaru The question is about what then? Don't use cron, use a worker process inside your supervision tree for it if possible. Are your referring to "how to create module"? Create a module like any other module, it does not differ. Maybe edit question, and be more clear?

Comment: I don't know whether it's shitty, I was just pointing at a potential example. Depending on your needs, the solution might be as simple as doing a `send_after`. Anyway, maintaining external cron jobs (you are using Chef or Puppet or Ansible or whatever for that, I hope?) is often a pain in the butt, full of surprises (as nowhere in your codebase it shows that a cronjob is (supposed to be) running, it's defined somewhere else), so usually I try to avoid them at all cost; and there are various ways to do that, not necessarily requiring an "unknown shitty dependency".